# Show column error when using msbuild.exe

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild

Is it possible to get the column number where the error occurred (mostly coming from cl.exe) in the output of `MSBuild.exe`?

I'd like to do this for binding F4 key properly on Sublime Text.

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.0.30319.17929
[Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.17929]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  'Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler Nov 2012 CTP' is for testing purposes only.
  Mesh.cpp
..\..\..\lib\Kernel\Mesh.cpp(94): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'return' [C:\Users\Stringer\Code\XXXXXXX\kernel\lib\Kernel\kernel.vcxproj]
[Finished in 1.4s]
```

Comment: If you change the logging verbosity to 'diagnostic', do you get the appropriate level of detail from cl.exe?

Comment: No, this doesn't change anything appart from MSBuild printing a lot of technical slang...

Comment: Technical Slang is Stack Overflow's primary language!  (you should post some of it, along with the visual studio version and if by "output of msbuild.exe" you mean "error pane in visual studio")

Comment: @Nick, I'm speaking of output of msbuild.exe in ST console, which is exactly the same than `Output` pane in VS2012.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with MSBuild.exe.  It is the C++ compiler that will not provide column number info.  It doesn't have an option to turn it on either.

This is inherent in the build model for C or C++.  The preprocessor gets a shot at the source code first and often significantly alters it.  The compiler itself can only see that pre-processed version of the source.  C++ compilers have a mechanism to preserve the original file name and line number ([see #line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5w2czay.aspx)) but not for column numbers, it isn't practical.

So no, missing column numbers is by design.

Notable is [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/diagnostics.html), a compiler project whose sole reason was to eliminate several of these fundamental C++ compilation restrictions.